# how to get SQLite to work in Mono for a ready WinForms application

Tags: sqlite, mono

I'm almost finished with an application of mine that I developed with M Visual Studio 2010 using c#.

The software uses a lot of SQLite transactions, all of which work perfect compiled and run under Windows.
Now I try to make my app multiplatform, using Mono (for the first time). And I can't seem to get Mono work with SQLite properly.

Run w Mono basically the first of almost any type of SQLite transaction makes the app instacrashquit.:(

I have a reference for
using System.Data.SQLite;

as a starting point.

Mono adapter tool MoMa throws 100 errors about this current .dll

I downloaded a dll called 
Mono.Data.Sqlite;
but as funny as it seems, MoMa throws around 100 other problems about this .dll too!

I'm sure I'm missing something as I'm pretty inexperienced yet especially w Mono, porting and other systems than Win.

Please help me what to do next!

Thx!

Best Regards

ZAX

Comment: Mono.Data.SQLite needs libsqlite3.so/sqlite3.dll, this usually comes with mono. Don't worry about MoMa for that

Comment: MoMA does report false alarms for assemblies that work on Mono (well, at least for me), so start to run and test on Mono/Linux directly is recommended.

Comment: Mono.Date.SQLite also works quite well on .Net, it is also a little faster than System.Data.SQLite ( all of these do have a common source ancestor, they are not very different in code )

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing the same thing, and finally got it to compile without errors.
Sadly, the SQLite methods have different case between Windows and Mono, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826408/sqlite-in-mono-sqliteconnection-could-not-be-found/40649591#40649591).

See also the help from others [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40636796/c-sharp-shortcut-for-if-else-endif-like-define-something-as-string?noredirect=1&lq=1).