# C# shortcut for #if ... #else ... #endif like #define something as string

Tags: c#, mono, conditional-compilation

In C# dotNET for Mono, is there an easier way of doing this?

```
#if __MonoCS__
    public static SqliteConnection NewConnection
#else
    public static SQLiteConnection NewConnection
#endif
```

In C I would be able to #if and then #define something, #else and define it as something else.

I know that the C# preprocessor doesn't allow what I want, but is there a simpler way of coping with the differences between SQLite for Windows and Linux?

Thanks,
Jim

---

Thanks to those who answered.
Files that depend on SQLite now contain statements like this at the beginning:

```
#if __MonoCS__
    using Mono.Data.Sqlite;
    using SQLiteCommand =     Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand;
    using SQLiteConnection =  Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection;
    using SQLiteException =   Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException;
    using SQLiteParameter =   Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteParameter;
    using SQLiteTransaction = Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteTransaction;
#else
    using System.Data.SQLite;
#endif
```

In C I would put all that in a .h file and #include it where needed. Is there a way to do that in a Mono C# project? Nothing I tried worked.

Thanks again,
Jim

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, you can use a using alias directive:

```
#if __MonoCS__
using SQLiteConnection = Foo.Bar.SqliteConnection;
#endif
```

Then you can use `SQLiteConnection` everywhere within the same file.

You may want to use the adapter pattern to put this just in a single piece of code though, so all the rest of your code can be the same either way.

Comment: @jon
what is difference between these two lines?
 #if __MonoCS__
    public static SqliteConnection NewConnection
#else
    public static SQLiteConnection NewConnection
#endif

Comment: @viveknuna: Look at the casing of `SQL`

Comment: Thanks. I ended up adding "using" statements near the front of each file that depends on SQLite. I can't format code in this comment, so I'll edit my original question.