# Anybody know why mono SQLite uses SqliteConnection but Windows uses SQLiteConnection?

Tags: c#, sqlite, mono, method-names

I am adapting a large open-source Windows program to Linux, using MonoDevelop.
I find that the SQLite method names in Windows look like this:

```
SQLiteConnection
```

but in Mono.Data.Sqlite they look like this:

```
SqliteConnection
```

with different case, so I got lots of reference errors.

With help from others at stackexchange [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40636796/c-sharp-shortcut-for-if-else-endif-like-define-something-as-string) I was able to get the projects to compile.

Do any of you know why the two different versions of SQLite have different case in the method names?

Comment: maybe because the SQLite binding library that you were using on Windows is not cross-platform? did you check the system requirements of it? can you provide the URL or nuget package name of each of the binding libraries?

Comment: The original developer of this software released the compiled .exe of the program and some DLL files, amongst them "System.Data.SQLite.DLL" with these Details: 
File description: System Data SQLite Interop Library, 
File version: 1.0.65.0, 
Product Name: System Data SQLite, 
Product version: 1.0, 
Date modified: 27-Jul-2009 2:38AM, 
Original filename: SQLite3.DLL 3.6.16
I am also corresponding on the sqlite user email list, where someone said there is a version for mono where the cases should be compatible. I haven't had time to check that out yet.